# Keep getting error message when trying to write a simple makefile in C++?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm having trouble getting my makefile to produce an executable. 
Here's the code in my makefile:

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x
CXXFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -g

LDFLAGS = -lboost_date_time

OBJS = f.o g.o lab1-2.o

SRCS = f.cpp g.cpp lab1-2.cpp

HEADERS = f.h g.h

#target: dependencies

#   rule to build


lab1-2: ${OBJS} ${HEADERS}
    ${CXX} ${LDFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o lab1-2


${OBJS}: ${SRCS}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c $(@: .o=.cpp)
```

When I call "make" this is what happens:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic-errors -g -c f.o;
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic-errors -g -c g.o;
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic-errors -g -c lab1-2.o;
"linker input file unused because linking not done"
```

I'm not sure what this message(above) means and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Please add the output of `make --just-print`.

Comment: `"linker input file unused because linking not done"` is a warning not an error. It is telling you that the compiler is ignoring linker arguments because you aren't performing linking at the moment.

Comment: Are there tabs at the start of the `${CXX}` lines? There should be. There also shouldn't be blank lines (that don't have tabs) between the `lab1-2: ...` and `${OBJS}: ...` line and the `${CXX} ...` lines.

Comment: Yes I put tabs at the start of the ${CXX} lines..sorry I don't know why it didn't show up. There any no blank lines in those spots..again a formatting error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `-c` flag tells the compiler front-end (`g++`) that it should compile the source file into an object file, then stop.  However you are giving an object file to the compiler (`f.o`, `g.o`, `lab1-2.o`), not a source file.  So the compiler is telling you that it's ignoring those object files, since you are compiling (`-c`) not linking.

Your makefile has problems.  For example:

```
${OBJS}: ${SRCS}
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c $(@: .o=.cpp)
```

is not what you want.  First, you cannot add whitespace after the `:` in a pattern reference like that.  Make is very particular about certain kinds of whitespace (as are all computer tools, really).  If the examples in the manual don't have whitespace it's best to not add any (and vice versa).  You want to say `$(@:.o=.cpp)` (no space).  Then your compile line will have the source file in it: `f.cpp`, `g.cpp`) not the object file.

Second, if you expand the variables you get:

```
f.o g.o lab1-2.o: f.cpp g.cpp lab1-2.cpp
```

which is identical to writing:

```
f.o: f.cpp g.cpp lab1-2.cpp
g.o: f.cpp g.cpp lab1-2.cpp
lab1-2.o: f.cpp g.cpp lab1-2.cpp
```

that is whenever you change ANY source file, ALL the object files will get rebuilt.  That's not what you want.  Also, since you don't list any header files here it means that none of these object files will be rebuilt because you changed a header file.

Finally, you have this:

```
lab1-2: ${OBJS} ${HEADERS}
```

where you have listed the header files as prerequisites of the *executable*, which is not right: you don't re-link the executable when header files change, you recompile the source files.

You want something like this:

```
lab1-2: ${OBJS}
        ${CXX} ${LDFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o lab1-2

$(OBJS): $(HEADERS)

%.o: %.cpp
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

Of course, GNU  make has built-in rules that do all this for you, so you COULD just write this:

```
lab1-2: ${OBJS}

$(OBJS): $(HEADERS)
```

to get the same results.